# Heroku url - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

I am trying to make a get request to the following url : https://arcane-shore-1097.herokuapp.com but I get the syntax error mentioned above.

Here is my code:

```
function getEvents(){
    var workingurl = "http://api.douban.com/v2/book/1220562";
    var url = "https://arcane-shore-1097.herokuapp.com";
    var results = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Get request succeeded" + data);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the output I get in the javascript console:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://arcane-shore-1097.herokuapp.com/?callback=jQuery21307401092585641891_1424034937433&_=1424034937434". jquery.min.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :   arcane-shore-1097.herokuapp.com/:1

I'm guessing the error has something to do with the fact that I'm getting json instead of jsonp from the server. But I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Do you get any error when you remove this function?

Comment: Change the server response from json to jsonp.